# SQL - Sum content of cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database with a table that very simplified looks like this

```
Column 1  Column 2 (varchar)
Vector 1  23^34^45^65
Vector 2  0^54^10^31
```

Now I want to sum the numbers in the cells of column 2 together. That is, I want it to look like this:

```
Column 1  Column 2 (varchar)
Vector 1  167
Vector 2  95
```

How do I do this in SQL?

Comment: Don't store data like that... It will only cause you lots of trouble. (One value / row is the SQL way.)

Comment: I agree with you on that, It looks very fishy to me. But in the situation I am in now this is what I have to deal with, I think, as I don't have administrator rights.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Product specific functionality will be needed.)

Comment: So is it possible at all? Cause I really don't think I can affect how the data is stored in this case.

I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio 2014

Comment: Are there always 5 numbers in column 2?

Comment: It is always 10. (Cut it down to simplify but it's always 10)

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server split".

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
SELECT a.col1, sum_of_values = SUM(d.val)
FROM (VALUES ('Vector 1', '23^34^45^65'), ('Vector 2', '0^54^10^31')) a (col1, col2)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(xml, '<a>' + REPLACE(a.col2, '^', '</a><a>')+'</a>')) AS b(doc)
CROSS APPLY b.doc.nodes('a') c (item)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.item.value('.', 'int')) d (val)
GROUP BY a.col1
```

Output:

```
col1     sum_of_values
-------- -------------
Vector 1 167
Vector 2 95
```

Explanation:

1. The `VALUES` clause is a placeholder for your data.
2. By `REPLACE`'ing caret (`^`) with XML tags we can use methods on the `xml` datatype to efficiently split values.
3. `CROSS APPLY` with the `nodes()` method of the `xml` datatype returns a new row per item, and an `xml` column containing the item value.
4. `value('.', 'int')` converts the inner text of an `<a>` element to an `int`.
5. The `GROUP BY` and `SUM` aggregate these results, and reduce the number of rows back to the original two.

Edit: You could move the split into its own function. Like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitIntOnCaret (@list varchar(max)) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
    SELECT Position = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    , Value = item.value('.', 'int')
    FROM (SELECT CONVERT(xml, '<a>' + REPLACE(@list, '^', '</a><a>')+'</a>')) AS a(doc)
    CROSS APPLY doc.nodes('a') c (item)
```

So your final query could look like this:

```
SELECT l.list_id, sum_of_values = SUM(s.value)
FROM dbo.MyLists l
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitIntOnCaret(l.list) AS s
GROUP BY l.list_id
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit how it works?Just genuinely curious.

Comment: @Mihai I have added an explanation to the answer

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to create a function so you can do this for more than 2 rows do you think?

Comment: Sure. I have added such a function to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the way your data is stored, you will have to

1. Split the String (see [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows))
2. Compute the `SUM` using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out.